# Remove Edit and delete button appearing in select box reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to `reactJS`. I have a select option.

I want to add delete and edit button inside the select option.

Here's the code i tried,

```
<Select
    style={{ width: 240 }}
    placeholder="Choose Web Analytics Configuration"
    dropdownRender={menu => (
    <div>
        {menu}
        <Divider style={{ margin: '4px 0' }} />
        <div
            style={{ padding: '4px 8px', cursor: 'pointer' }}
            onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
            onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}
        >
            <Icon type="plus" /> Add  Database
        </div>
    </div>
    )}
        >
    {dbConfigList.map(item => (
        <Option  key={item}>{item} 
        <Icon onClick={this.editFun.bind(this)} type="edit" style={{ fontSize: '20px', color: 'green' }} theme="outlined" /> 
        <Icon onClick={this.deleteFun.bind(this)} type="delete" style={{ fontSize: '20px', color: '#CC160B' }} theme="outlined" /> 
        </Option>

    ))}
</Select>
```

I have successfully added the buttons. 
Here it looks like:

[image]

But when the User selects the option, the edit and delete button appears in the select box. I only needed the name to be shown and not buttons.

Here it looks like,

[image]

Help me with some solutions to fix it and inside the `dropdown` menu of every each option, I want the edit and delete buttons to be appeared at the right corner. Now it was appearing after the text. i can use margin for that. but every name size differs. Ex. Some names will be 6 characters and some will be more than 6 characters. Help me with some solutions.

Comment: add condition in your `dbConfigList.map` to prevent `<Icon>` when option is selected.

Comment: @Jigar Shah, How to add condition inside map. I haven't added there before. can u show me some examples

Comment: @Paul Can you please add a working demo? Because from your code we never know what props needed by Select and Option

Comment: @Paul I think Option or Select may have value prop in it and you can pass item in the value.

Comment: @PaulSteven check added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below example, you need to prevent your `<Icon>` as I had done for '+ -'

should be like:

```
{
  dbConfigList.map(item => (
    <Option key={item}>
      {item}
      {selectedValue !== item // you need to add state 
      <Icon
        onClick={this.editFun.bind(this)}
        type="edit"
        style={{ fontSize: "20px", color: "green" }}
        theme="outlined"
      />
      <Icon
        onClick={this.deleteFun.bind(this)}
        type="delete"
        style={{ fontSize: "20px", color: "#CC160B" }}
        theme="outlined"
      /> : null}
    </Option>
  ));
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      optionsdata : [
         {key:'101',value:'Lion'},
         {key:'102',value:'Giraffe'},
         {key:'103',value:'Zebra'},
         {key:'104',value:'Hippo'},
         {key:'105',value:'Penguin'}
       ],
      selectedValue: null // store selected value
    }
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    var value = this.state.optionsdata.filter(function(item) {
      return item.key == e.target.value
    })
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value[0].value }); // set state
    console.log(value[0].value);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.optionsdata.map(function(data, key) {  return (
          <option key={key} value={data.key}>{data.value} {selectedValue !== data.value ? '+ -' : null } </option> )
        })}
      </select>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo App: https://codesandbox.io/s/button-in-select-menuitem-reactjs-demo-1zyvj 
I solved this problem in material-Ui design by using **onOpen={() => setIconVisibile(true)}** and **onClose={() => setIconVisibile(false)}** callbacks to set the visibility of icons.

```
const [isIconVisibile, setIconVisibile] = React.useState(false);
<Select   
    onOpen={() => setIconVisibile(true)}
    onClose={() => setIconVisibile(false)} 
  >
    <MenuItem value={1}>
      {"ONE"}
      {isIconVisibile ? (
        <ListItemSecondaryAction variant="outlined">
          <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete">
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      ) : null}
    </MenuItem> 
  </Select>
```